# Ruby writing hash key as file name and values as text

Tags: ruby, file, hash, symbols

I have a hash that has a keys with multiple values. I would like to create a new files with the key values being the file names. Then I would like to add each value element on a new line of the file.

However I am getting the following error:

`initialize': no implicit conversion of Symbol into String (TypeError)

```
    @agency_list.each do |domain, email|
        File.open(domain , "w") { |file| file.write(email) }
    end
```

I tried to convert the value elements to strings but that did not change anything.

Comment: Add your hash to the question.

Comment: The hash is huge and dynamic. Basically it consists as email domains as the keys and email addresses as the values.

Comment: Are you using symbols (like `:foo`) as keys or values? If so, how are you converting them to strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you use symbol in the place where a string should be put into.

Because the information is limited. Try change:

```
File.open(domain , "w") { |file| file.write(email) }
```

to

```
File.open(domain.to_s , "w") { |file| file.write(email) }
```

and

```
File.open(domain , "w") { |file| file.write(email.to_s) }
```

Or add "to_s" to both `"domain"` and `"email"` to check which one is correct then you might know which part is wrong.